# Ng-style function called more than once

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/88JCS1qZ5yFVCi676Oan?p=preview) I have a div with a border width that is determined by the value in an input field. I achieve that with `ng-style` containing a `getBorder()` function.

My issue is that `getBorder()` is called twice and sometimes three times, instead of once. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

HTML

```
    Width: <input type="number" ng-model="borderWidth"/>
    <br/>
    <div style="background-color:orange;height:200px;width:100px" 
         ng-style="{ 'border': getBorder() }"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.getBorder = function(){
      alert('getBorder called');
      return $scope.borderWidth + 'px solid black';
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the [digest cycles](https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/) in AngularJS.

AngularJS registers watchers to observe changes in the scope, and as soon as a change happens, it refreshes the bindings between corresponding views/models using digest cycles. This is the reason why you can see live changes in the data and on the screen.

[`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) is one of the directives which registers a watcher. So, the problem you came across, is not really a problem, because `ng-style` is trying to get the value using `getBorder()`.

Comment: Are there any performance implications? When my application starts the `getBorder()` function is called more than 80 times, probably called each time when there's a cycle for whatever reason.

Comment: @ps0604 -- the function will be called everytime the binding changes i.e. whenever the value of `ng-model` changes, in your case. This is the only way AngularJS can do these things. In terms of performance, yes, you may notice a lag in your browser if you have hundreds of such watchers. But having one watcher doesn't make that much impact.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this solution solved your problem

```js
   var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.borderWidth = 1;

        $scope.$watch('borderWidth', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log()
          if (angular.isDefined(newVal)) {
            $scope.styleBorder = newVal + 'px solid black';
          }
        });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <html ng-app="app">
      <body>
        <div ng-controller="ctl">
            Width: <input type="number" ng-model="borderWidth"/>
            <br/>
            <div
              style="background-color:orange;height:200px;width:100px;"
              ng-style='{"border": styleBorder}'
            ></div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is somewhat similar to having `ng-model` in the code. Registering a watcher manually doesn't solve this problem.